# javascript call stack main function

Tags: javascript, node.js

Watching this Philip Roberts talk at JSConf 2014 at this point
https://youtu.be/8aGhZQkoFbQ?t=12m38s
In the setTimeout execution example I see a main() function pushed in the call stack at first.
What's that function? Could I have any information about it?

I indeed saw using the browser debugger there is always an anonymous function as first element of the stack. But I'm not sure it's the same thing. If so, the odd part is when the setTimeout callback is pushed in the stack: there is no main().

Comment: I'm assuming `main()` refers to the script that's being executed. It has finished by the time the callback is evaluated.

Comment: I think is some kind of 'wrapper' of any function executed. But in this case it should be there even when `cb()` is executed (another `main()`)..

Comment: Well then obviously it's not a wrapper for any function if it doesn't appear for all functions.

Comment: when it doesn't appear? Using the browser debugger I mean, not in the video example.

Comment: to be more clear about my previous comment: just try to debug step by step some sync and async function..you will see always an anonymous function as first element of the stack.

Comment: Are you asking about the video or about what a specific browser does? The guy on the video is clearly simplifying things.

Comment: Basically I would expect at 14:09, when `cb()` is pushed in the stack, another `main()` function would be pushed first.

Comment: Surely the speaker would leave out such details that are irrelevant to the presentation. The topic is about the event loop in general, not every minuscule detail of what the browser might do.